# Docker 1.12 Swarm Mode - Load balance tasks of the same service on single node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

On Docker 1.12 Swarm Mode, if i have more than one task of the same service running in a single node and publishing the same port, is possible to do any kind of load balance between the tasks? Or, whats the purpose of having more instances of a service than the number of nodes?
Eg.

```
node swarm init
node service create --name web --replicas=2 --publish=80:80 nginx
```

Now if i open the browser and access http://localhost/ (refreshing the page many times) all connections seems to be handled by the same task, as could be seem by doing:

```
docker logs [container1]
docker logs [container2]
```

PS: Ok, i know that makes no sense having a swarm of a single node, but the same seems to occur if i have 10 nodes on the swarm (with a service scaled to 10 replicas), and then i lose one of those nodes (2 tasks of the service will be running on the same node and one of them will never receive connections).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the routing mesh does distribute requests among all the containers, even if several containers are running on the same node.

You don't see that with the stock `nginx` image because it's configured with a high keep-alive setting, so your client keeps returning to the same container when you refresh.

Try this custom Nginx image instead:

```
docker service create --name nginx --replicas 10 -p 80:80 sixeyed/nginx-with-hostname
```

([sixeyed/nginx-with-hostname](https://hub.docker.com/r/sixeyed/nginx-with-hostname/) is an automated build, you can check the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/sixeyed/dockers/tree/master/nginx-with-hostname).)

There's a 1-second keep-alive specified, and a custom response header `X-Host` which tells you the hostname of the server - in this case it will be the container ID.

I made three successive requests, which all got served by different containers:

```
> curl -k http://my-swarm.com/ | grep X-Host
X-Host: 5920bc3c7659 

> curl -k http://my-swarm.com/ | grep X-Host    
X-Host: eb228bb39f58 

> curl -k http://my-swarm.com/ | grep X-Host
X-Host: 891bafd52c90
```

Those containers all happen to be running on the manager node in a 2-node swarm. Other requests got served by containers on the worker, so Docker is distributing them around all the tasks.