# Docker service create `n` replicas in `n-1` swarm nodes

Tags: docker

I have **4** nodes in a Docker swarm. I create a service with official docker nginx image with **5** replicas. If I use a port mapping 80:80, only 4 containers are accessible publicly; the other one is inaccessible.

```
docker service create --name web -p 80:80 --replicas 5 nginx
```

Is there a way, I can make all the 5 nginx-running-containers publicly accessible? (two of the containers are in the same node and only one can bind to node's port 80)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create `n` replicas of a service, they do all participate in load-balancing for the service. If one node has several instances of the service running, when the host gets a request on port 80, Docker will distribute traffic among the containers on that host.

With your 5 replicas on 4 nodes, if you throw some test traffic and check the responses, you should see that all five containers are responding. But it's difficult to check that with the default `nginx` image. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647064/docker-1-12-swarm-mode-load-balance-tasks-of-the-same-service-on-single-node/39649010#39649010) uses an alternative image as a simple to verify all the containers are responding to traffic.

Comment: Thanks! I tested your custom nginx image and now have a good understanding. What a coincidence... when I started delving into information on swarm mode this week, your walk-through on youtube (KC4Ad1DS8xU) was the first thing I watched.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge that is not possible unless at-least one of the servers has multiple public LAN cards / virtual networks attached. Not sure though why you would want more than one nginx instance running per node.

Comment: Well, I am learning about docker swarm and services and how to use them; this is indeed a theoretical question.