# Docker swarm load balancing on AWS not working

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

Just getting going with swarm on AWS. I'm able to create my cluster with docker-machine, init swarm and spin up a service. But I'm **struggling to get the load balancing working**.

I'm only able to curl the app on the hosts that it's been deployed on, other hosts do not forward on requests, no round-robin going on.

I'm using the following scripts to test my cluster. Any clues would be great, getting a bit stuck here.

```
!/bin/bash
aws_region=eu-west-1
instances=6

n=1
while [ $n -le $instances ]
do
machine_name=$aws_region-$n
docker-machine create \
--driver amazonec2 \
--amazonec2-region $aws_region \
--amazonec2-security-group 'swarm-cluster' \
$machine_name &
n=$(( n + 1 ))
done

!/bin/bash
Init managers
hostname="eu-west-1-1"
echo $hostname
manager_ip="$(docker-machine inspect $hostname | jq -r '.Driver.PrivateIPAddress'):2377"
docker $(docker-machine config $hostname) swarm init --advertise-addr $manager_ip --listen-addr $manager_ip

manager_token="$(docker $(docker-machine config $hostname) swarm join-token manager -q)"
worker_token="$(docker $(docker-machine config $hostname) swarm join-token worker -q)"

hostname="eu-west-1-2"
echo $hostname
ip="$(docker-machine inspect $hostname | jq -r '.Driver.PrivateIPAddress'):2377"
docker $(docker-machine config $hostname) swarm join \
--token $manager_token \
$manager_ip \
--advertise-addr $ip --listen-addr $ip

hostname="eu-west-1-3"
echo $hostname
ip="$(docker-machine inspect $hostname | jq -r '.Driver.PrivateIPAddress'):2377"
docker $(docker-machine config $hostname) swarm join \
--token $manager_token \
$manager_ip \
--advertise-addr $ip --listen-addr $ip

Init workers
hostname="eu-west-1-4"
echo $hostname
ip="$(docker-machine inspect $hostname | jq -r '.Driver.PrivateIPAddress'):2377"
docker $(docker-machine config $hostname) swarm join \
--token $worker_token \
$manager_ip \
--advertise-addr $ip --listen-addr $ip

hostname="eu-west-1-5"
echo $hostname
ip="$(docker-machine inspect $hostname | jq -r '.Driver.PrivateIPAddress'):2377"
docker $(docker-machine config $hostname) swarm join \
--token $worker_token \
$manager_ip \
--advertise-addr $ip --listen-addr $ip

hostname="eu-west-1-6"
echo $hostname
ip="$(docker-machine inspect $hostname | jq -r '.Driver.PrivateIPAddress'):2377"
docker $(docker-machine config $hostname) swarm join \
--token $worker_token \
$manager_ip \
--advertise-addr $ip --listen-addr $ip

eval $(docker-machine env eu-west-1-1)

docker service create --name web --replicas 3 --mount type=bind,src=/etc/hostname,dst=/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html,readonly --publish 80:80 nginx
```

Comment: What happens when you `curl` one of the other machines? The `nginx` image has a high keep-alive setting, so if you're just testing load balancing try the image [from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647064/docker-1-12-swarm-mode-load-balance-tasks-of-the-same-service-on-single-node/39649010#39649010)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, in the region sa-east-1. This exacltly same cluster configuration is running well, in a local virtual machine on VirtualBox:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:58:26 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:58:26 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```